# Random number generation

Tags: random-generation, genetic-algorithms

Generating n random variables whose summation will be 1. [*I got the answer.*]

**EDIT**

On genetic algorithm, we have to maintain population. Say, I have two individuals **a** and **b**. Every individual consists of $n$ pairs of ($x_i, \theta_i$), where $ 0 \leq i < n$. A fitness function evaluates fitness, $f$ of every individual. **Constraint is for every individual is $\Sigma\theta_i \approx 1$ ($0.95 \leq \Sigma\theta_i < 1.05$ would suffice).** $\theta_i$ associated with individual **a** will be adapted by some function (which I haven't figured out yet) of $d(a, b)$ & $\Delta f$. $\theta_i$ will be adaptive (by I guess something like covariance matrix). So if I increase value of $\theta_i$, values of some $\theta_j$ have to be decreased to maintain summation $\Sigma\theta_i \approx 1$. So I am seeking suggestion how can be $\theta_i$ adapted based on $d(a, b)$ & $\Delta f$?

Comment: **Questions**: What do you mean by "parameter"? (Do you mean you want to generate $n$ *random variates* according to your condition?) What do you mean by "error margin"? What other (distributional, etc.) constraints would you like to be satisfied? The answer to your question is undoubtedly **yes**, but how to go about it will depend other details of your problem. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, question is edited. TIA

Comment: One answer: generate $n$ random values.  Divide each by their total.  This works whenever their total is nonzero.  The generality of this solution highlights the real question: *how do you want those random values to be distributed*?

Comment: @whuber: great solution. You have solved another problem of mine. Wish I could vote up you more.

Comment: @whuber: this is may be silly question. The range of generated value 1<*x*<100 or 1<*x*<10, will it make any difference between these range?

Comment: @crucified If you are generating only integers, then the resolution of the final values will be finer when the ranges are greater.  Otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: @whuber: So, in a word, your method is range invariant? What if, i use different ranges for generating n variables for different individuals, will it make any difference?

Comment: @crucified I think it would be good for you to experiment so you can understand what this simple formula does and see what it does *not* do.  In particular, my reply has not specified *any* method to generate the random values.  *That* is the important consideration.  You already have two specific replies (one of which is a special case of the other), but they don't begin to describe the scope of the possibilities.  Again: *how do you need the numbers to be distributed?*

Comment: @whuber FWIW, question is edited again. I don't know how much I clarified it. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is that of generating pseudo random numbers on the edges of a simplex. The best method is to:

1. Generate $x_1,...,x_{n^2}\sim \exp(1)$,
2. Stacke them in a $n\times n$ matrix,
3. Divide them by their row-wise sum.

I can't find a seminal paper now, but you should look for the algorithms described [here](http://www.qhull.org/html/rbox.htm).

Comment: Here is a reference for your answer: "Andrew Gelman, Bayesian Data
Analysis, pp.482" as given here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/22703

Comment: This is just a special case of @Harsh's answer. Also, what do you mean by "the best method"?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I generate n random numbers whose summation will be around 1?

You can try the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#String_cutting) (see also,  https://statipedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dirichlet).

You need to specify more details about how they're distributed; using only the sum-constraint condition allows too many possible distributions over parameters. The Dirichlet is a commonly used distribution which satisfies this property.